# PHP/Guzzle Target parent element

Tags: php, arrays, json, guzzle

I have an app using guzzle/php to make requests to a rest service.

When it yields a response, it includes nested arrays and objects:

[exampleBalances] => Array (
 
  [0] => stdClass Object (
 
   [balance] => 6 
   [name] => Prize One 
   [prizeCode] => 38 
  ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( 
   [balance] => 5 
   [name] => Prize Two 
   [prizeCode] => 20 
  ) 
  [2] => stdClass Object ( 
   [balance] => 4 
   [name] => Prize Four 
   [prizeCode] => 39 
  ) 
 )

Until now Ive been pulling the value based on the order:

$prizeThree = $response->exampleBalances['3']->balance;

However, the service wont display any 'prizes' if the customer has 0, so the example above would no longer be accurate if a new item was added:

[exampleBalances] => Array (
 
  [0] => stdClass Object (
 
   [balance] => 6 
   [name] => Prize One 
   [prizeCode] => 38 
  ) 
  [1] => stdClass Object ( 
   [balance] => 5 
   [name] => Prize Two 
   [prizeCode] => 20 
  ) 
  [2] => stdClass Object ( 
   [balance] => 8 
   [name] => Prize Three 
   [prizeCode] => 54 
  ) 
  [3] => stdClass Object ( 
   [balance] => 4 
   [name] => Prize Four 
   [prizeCode] => 39 
  ) 
 )

Is there a way to target the correct element, without using the order that it appears in the response?

I could not find any documentation, but its difficult to convey the issue. I was thinking there may be someway to create a condition to check an elements inner values (preferably the 'prize code') Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In PHP 5.5.0 or newer, you can use the array_column() function to do this search:

```
$index = array_search($prizeCodeSearch, array_column($exampleBalances, 'prizeCode'));
$element = $exampleBalances[$index];
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, Thank you!

This is specifically how I ended up using this:

// wallet codes:
$rollerCode = 16;
$beverageCode = 39;
 $gallonCode = 20;

// main function:

function someFunc($re,$wallet) {
            $index = array_search($wallet, array_column($re->rewardBalances, 'walletCode'));
            echo $re->rewardBalances[$index]->balance;
}


To Pull the values:
<p>Free Beverages: <?php someFunc($response,$beverageCode); ?></p>